# SimpleSwingApplication created a seemingly infinite amount of identical windows

Tags: swing, scala, scala-swing

So I have the following simple program in scala:

```
object CViewerMainWindow extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    var i = 0
    def top = new MainFrame {
        title = "Hello, World!"
        preferredSize = new Dimension(320, 240)
        // maximize
        visible = true
        contents = new Label("Here is the contents!")
        listenTo(top)
        reactions += {
            case UIElementResized(source) => println(source.size)

    }
}
```

.

```
object CViewer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val coreWindow = CViewerMainWindow
    coreWindow.top
  }
}
```

I had hoped it would create a plain window. Instead I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an infinite loop:

```
def top = new MainFrame {
  listenTo(top)
}
```

That is, `top` is calling `top` is calling `top`... The following should work:

```
def top = new MainFrame {
  listenTo(this)
}
```

But a better and safer approach is to forbid that the main frame is instantiated more than once:

```
lazy val top = new MainFrame {
  listenTo(this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.